# Java2D help to show filling something to image

Tags: java, awt

I'm doing a project to implement virtual chemistry laboratory system. I tried to do this by using java2D. I have come across a big issue here. that is how to show some kind of filling effect to a beaker or to a flask (beaker is an image). I tried out this with setPixel() method in WritableRaster(java.awt.image) class. but it is not much useful.

I need a help to show something filling to a beaker and to show color change when mixing two chemicals. please remember that beaker is an image. thanks in advance if anyone can give me a solution with sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Conveniently, many classes implement the [`Shape`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) interface. Implementing classes work well with `fill()`, as shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon). To display color transitions, consider `AlphaComposite`, shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite).

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise using a dynamic SVG canvas using [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/scripting/java.html), and then you can use advanced high-level features like masks and blending and such. It's not the most efficient solution, but who cares? It's flexible for the future. Also, it'd take a lot of optimisation to work out what parts of the image have actually changed and pass that through for efficiency. I expect Batik does that as standard. Also, you'll have something that looks really very nice.

Anyway, then you just need to use Inkscape to create the SVG, and then modify the DOM (Document Object Model) accordingly. It's just like messing with HTML. [Here](http://www.openclipart.org/search/?query=beaker) is some SVG beaker clipart.